# Where to place the Emailer class in the solution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, structure

I have a solution that has the following structure:

```
- My Solution
-- Core
--- Core.Interfaces (DLL)
--- Core.Data (DLL)
--- Core.Business (DLL)
-- Models
--- Models.Enums (DLL)
--- Models.DTOs (DLL)
--- Models.Model (DLL)
-- Clients
--- Client Access (ASP.NET MVC)
--- Management Access (ASP.NET)
```

Now I have an emailer class (IEmailer and Emailer) that will be used in both clients and mainly in the Core.Business as well, my initial thought is to place it in the Core.Business project.

Is that the logical place for the emailer class?

Comment: Thar will depend very much on your architecture. We just have the names of the assemblies, but not what's in them.

Comment: @safe I made the names simple to explain what they do, so data is basically the data access objects, business is the business objects and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add `IEmailer` to the `Core.Interfaces` and `Emailer` to a new assembly, something like `Infrastructure.Services`. There isn't much benefit in having the interface and implementation in the same assembly.

Next, I would assure that `Core.Business` has no direct dependency on the `Infrastructure.Services` assembly, hence on the `Emailer` type.